# Node.js post data that isn't a form

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder icon, which when a user clicks on, I want to be able to find out what folder it in my node.js server.

HTML:

```
<header>
<script>

    function newfile(filecode){
        console.log(filecode)
        $.post('/Y9computing', filecode).done()
    }


</script>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="folderIcon" onclick="newfile('Y9UNIT1')"></div>
</body>
```

node.js:

```
app.post('/Y9computing', function (req, res) {
    console.log("FIRED!")
    console.log(req.filecode) //don't know what to put in here
```

At the moment, the server logs "FIRED!" and then "undefined", I also think I'll have to respond from the server with something.

Comment: did you try req.body.filecode?

Comment: @madox2 Yep, still appearing as undefined. I feel like that must be problem though, because it logs the correct variable client side.

Comment: try to use: $.post( "/Y9computing", { filecode: filecode } ); on client

Comment: @madox2 Wow, that's done it, thanks!